# Is there a faster method to find words beginning with string inside a string?

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a field called `keywords` on Core Data that stores keywords separated by spaces, like:

```
car nascar race daytona crash
```

I have a list populated by core data. Every element on that list has keywords.

I have a search field on that view.

I want that list to be filtered as the user types.

If the user types `c` the app will check elements that have keywords beginning with `c`. In that case, the element mentioned above will be shown because it has `car` and `crash`, both beginning with `c`.

In order to check that, I created this extension

```
extension String {

  func containsWordStartingWith(insensitive searchWord: String) -> Bool {
    let lowercaseSelf = self.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    let lowercaseSearch = searchWord.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    
    let array = lowercaseSelf.components(separatedBy: " ")
    return array.contains(where: {$0.hasPrefix(lowercaseSearch)})
  }
}
```

This works but is slow as hell and typing characters on the search bar makes the app stall.

How can I improve that with something faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is split the single keywords string into a Set of actual keywords. If possible you should even store it in Core Data that way, so there's no need for a split step.

```
let keywords = "car nascar race daytona crash"
let keywordSet = Set(keywords.split(separator: " "))
```

Now the utility method you want is trivial and fast:

```
func keywordSet(_ set : Set<Substring>, containsWordStartingWith s: Substring) -> Bool {
    for keyword in set {
        if keyword.hasPrefix(s) { return true }
    }
    return false
}
```

Testing:

```
keywordSet(keywordSet, containsWordStartingWith:"c")
```

Comment: Sorry about the Substring types everywhere. You could convert to String if necessary.

Comment: I have tried your method but, unfortunately, it does not increase the speed, compared to mine. Because this is cleaner than mine, I will accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's not a good reason for accepting. If it isn't faster, please unaccept.